# How to set Ornstein-Uhlenbeck function with deterministic, not a constant parameter

Tags: random-process

I want to calculate Mean and Variance of this equation

$$r(t) = x(t) +y(t) + k(t),  r(0) = r_0,$$

$$dx(t) = -ax(t)dt + σdW_1(t), x(0) = 0,$$
$$dy(t) = -by(t)dt + ηdW_2(t), y(0) = 0,$$

Where $W_n(t)$ is Brownian motion. And $W_1(t) , W_2(t)$ is a two-dimensional Brownian motion with instantaneous correlation $ρ$.

So, $$dW_1(t)dW_2(t) = ρdt$$

**What I tried to do :**
I refer this documents, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess.html
Using the Orhstein-Uhlenbeck Process function, I tried to mimic the above equation. And it seems successful when the parameter is constant.

**The Problem is :**
In that link, It seems there are no case that parameter is deterministic function of some variable(In my case '$t$').

I mean, When the equation is like this $a$(constant) is changed $a(t)$(deterministic function of time $t$), $σ$ is changed $σ(t)$ and else..
$$r(t) = x(t) +y(t) + k(t),  r(0) = r_0,$$

$$dx(t) = -a(t)x(t)dt + σ(t)dW_1(t), x(0) = 0,$$
$$dy(t) = -b(t)y(t)dt + η(t)dW_2(t), y(0) = 0,$$

**My mathematica code is :**

`Mean[OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, \[Sigma][t], a[t], x][t-s]]`

However, it seems the mathematica deals with `a[t], \[sigma][t]` as just constant.
Because the outcome is just same as when the parameter is constant.

**Expectation and variance from my textbook when the parameter is constant :**
[image]

**Expectation and variance from my mathematica code when the parameter is function of time $t$:**
[image]

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code about the equation.

Comment: @cvgmt I just only use two lines of codes. First : Mean[OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, \[Sigma][t], a[t], x][t-s]] And Second : Variance[OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, \[Sigma][t], a[t], x][t-s]]. Because the two equations in my question can be expressed as OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess

Comment: The documentation clearly says "`OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[\[Mu],\[Sigma],\[Theta]]` 
represents a stationary Ornstein\[Dash]Uhlenbeck process with long-term mean `\[Mu]`, volatility `\[Sigma]`, and mean reversion speed `\[Theta]`".

Comment: Wiki and the search in Google bring nothing about such a modification of Ornstein- Uhlenbeck process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer.
I think that your *Mathematica* code does not represent the equation you seem to have in mind.

Warm-up:

```
procWarmup = 
 ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -a x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma]  \[DifferentialD]W1[t], 
             \[DifferentialD]y[t] == -b y[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
               \[Eta] (\[Rho] \[DifferentialD]W1[t] + Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]^2] \[DifferentialD]W2[t])}, 
             x[t] + y[t], {{x, y}, {x0, y0}}, {t, 0}, 
             {W1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], W2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}];

Mean[procWarmup[t]]
(* E^(-a t) x0 + E^(-b t) y0 *)

Variance[procWarmup[t]] // FullSimplify
(* (E^(-2 (a + b) t) (-4 a b E^((a + b) t) \[Eta] \[Rho] \[Sigma] + 
   E^(2 (a + b) t) (a (a + b) \[Eta]^2 + 
      4 a b \[Eta] \[Rho] \[Sigma] + b (a + b) \[Sigma]^2) - (a + 
      b) (a E^(2 a t) \[Eta]^2 + b E^(2 b t) \[Sigma]^2)))/(2 a b (a +
    b)) *)
```

Non constant parameters:

```
proc = ItoProcess[
 {\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -a[t] x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma][t] \[DifferentialD]W1[t], 
  \[DifferentialD]y[t] == -b[t]  y[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
    \[Eta][t] (\[Rho] \[DifferentialD]W1[t] + Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]^2] \[DifferentialD]W2[t])}, 
   x[t] + y[t], {{x, y}, {x0, y0}}, {t, 0}, 
   {W1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], W2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}];

Mean[proc[t]]
(* E^(-Inactive[Integrate][-a[K[1]], {K[1], 1, 0}] + Inactive[Integrate][-a[K[1]], {K[1], 1, t}]) x0 + 
   E^(-Inactive[Integrate][-b[K[2]], {K[2], 1, 0}] + Inactive[Integrate][-b[K[2]], {K[2], 1, t}]) y0 *)
```

This is different compared to what you reported (and I think it's correct).

```
Variance[proc[t]]
(* Some parts make sense, some look like gibberish *)
```

It might be helpful to report the last bit to Wolfram.

Comment: It is very helpful answer to me. However, When I copy your procWarmup and Paste it to my mathematica online and evaluate Mean[procWarmup[t]], it just give value '0'. So I cannot follow your reply now. Am I right to follow your answer?

Comment: It works for me, maybe try a fresh session/kernel ?